# Switched from Lucene to Solr: "Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/FieldReaders"

Tags: solr, versions

I am upgrading from 8.1 to 9.1, and I'm switching to Solr before the actual upgrade.

I have a rather elaborate custom index configuration, and I converted it to Solr at the best of my knowledge. The configuration node mentioned in the title exists both in the default Solr configuration and in my custom one, but it's not being detected for some reason.

I used Dotpeek to see what's happening under the hood but was unable to determine what exactly is going wrong.

I am also unable to access `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` as the web application does not start.

**Question**

What is the best way to troubleshoot my configuration error? Should I perhaps use the one that comes with my Sitecore release and then gradually change it file-by-file until it matches mine, or what else?

Comment: I think that's the best way to it which you also mentioned: "use the one that comes with my Sitecore release and then gradually change it file-by-file until it matches mine".

Comment: it seems you're missing the field readers node in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config file.

Comment: Extract the App_Config folder and use beyond compare to compare your app_config with the vanilla App_Config folder.

Comment: Make sure to remove the `.example` or `.disabled` extension for the config `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`?

Comment: Download Sitecore Config Builder from the market place. Verify your configs before you do anything else.

Comment: Don't forget that you can use the good and old SIM Tool to generate your fake `showconfig.aspx` you this page won't load.

Comment: Where can I get this tool Hugo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing my entire config with the default one of my current Sitecore release, I was able to pin-point which specific file was causing the error by gradually replacing it with my own config.